# Cross products of elements of 3D array and matrix columns without loop in R

Tags: arrays, r, performance, loops, matrix

I'm working on a fishery stock assessment model and want to speed it up by removing a loop (actually two loops of the same form).
I have an array, A, dim(A)=[L,L,Y], and a matrix, M, dim(M)=[L,Y].
These are used to make a matrix, mat, dim(mat)=[L,Y], by calculating matrix products. My loop looks like:

```
for(i in 1:Y){
mat[,i]<-(A[,,i]%*%M[,i])[,1]}
```

Can anyone help me out? I really need a speed gain.
Also, (don't know if it'll make a difference but) each A[,,i] matrix is lower triangular.

Comment: I think the key would be to eliminate all the computations that don't contribute to the first column. You should post a simplified example.

Comment: The last subset-to-first column is redundant. The matrix multiplication inside the loop yields only one column anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will give you the results you want. Since there is no reproducible example, I can't be absolutely sure. Had to trace some of the linear algebra logic to see what you are trying to accomplish.

```
library(plyr) # We need this to split the array into a list of 9 matrices
B = lapply(alply(A, 3), function(x) (x%*%M)) # Perform 9 linear algebra multiplications
sapply(1:9, function(i) (B[[i]])[,i]) # Extract the 9 columns you actually want.
```

I used the following test data:

```
A = array(rnorm(225), dim = c(5,5,9))
M = matrix(rnorm(45), nrow = 5, ncol = 9)
```

Comment: Isn't this slower than the for loop?

Comment: I don't know since OP code doesn't actually run for me. Thinking about it, it is probably slower...we'll see. I'll delete when OP replies.

Comment: OP code ran for me. just replace Y with ncol(M) and add mat <- matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(M), nrow=nrow(M)) somewhere.

And it was faster than plyr. Not sure if this is a property of plyr itself or not. Anyway OP is not replying so probably it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: That's great, thank you. It does produce the correct results. I was unaware of the alply function - very useful.

Comment: It is slower though. I tried it on my data hoping it would be quicker on bigger matrices but it isn't.